# How do I show Advanced Custom Fields from an Options Page from a Group in Twig/Timber - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber, acfpro

So if I have a group of fields on my Options page called ***product_tools*** and 3 fields within that of ***tool_link, tool_picture, and tool_name*** I am trying to get that out on a page with twig but it's not working for me? `{{ options.product_tools.tool.name }}` when I do a dump I get all the fields in an array just fine.

Here is the dump:  `{{ dump(options.product_tools) }}`

```
C:\Users\WpDev\Local Sites\protoolsite\app\public\wp-content\plugins\timber-library\vendor\twig\twig\src\Extension\DebugExtension.php:70:
array (size=3)
  'tool_link' => string 'https://www.dewalt.com/products/power-tools' (length=43)
  'tool_picture' => 
    array (size=24)
      'ID' => int 307
      'id' => int 307
      'title' => string 'band-saw' (length=8)
      'filename' => string 'band-saw.jpg' (length=12)
      'filesize' => int 103647
      'url' => string 'http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/band-saw.jpg' (length=69)
      'link' => string 'http://protoolsite.local/band-saw/' (length=39)
      'alt' => string '' (length=0)
      'author' => string '1' (length=1)
      'description' => string '' (length=0)
      'caption' => string '' (length=0)
      'name' => string 'band-saw' (length=8)
      'status' => string 'inherit' (length=7)
      'uploaded_to' => int 0
      'date' => string '2021-07-13 14:37:29' (length=19)
      'modified' => string '2021-07-13 14:37:29' (length=19)
      'menu_order' => int 0
      'mime_type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'image' (length=5)
      'subtype' => string 'jpeg' (length=4)
      'icon' => string 'http://protoolsite.local/wp-includes/images/media/default.png' (length=66)
      'width' => int 1000
      'height' => int 1000
      'sizes' => 
        array (size=18)
          'thumbnail' => string 'http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/band-saw-150x150.jpg' (length=77)
          'thumbnail-width' => int 150
          'thumbnail-height' => int 150
          'medium' => string 'http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/band-saw-300x300.jpg' (length=77)
          'medium-width' => int 300
          'medium-height' => int 300
          'medium_large' => string 'http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/band-saw-768x768.jpg' (length=77)
          'medium_large-width' => int 768
          'medium_large-height' => int 768
          'large' => string 'http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/band-saw.jpg' (length=69)
          'large-width' => int 1000
          'large-height' => int 1000
          '1536x1536' => string 'http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/band-saw.jpg' (length=69)
          '1536x1536-width' => int 1000
          '1536x1536-height' => int 1000
          '2048x2048' => string 'http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/band-saw.jpg' (length=69)
          '2048x2048-width' => int 1000
          '2048x2048-height' => int 1000
  'tool_name' => string 'Dewalt Bandsaw' (length=14)
```

Comment: Instead of `{{ options.product_tools.tool.name }}` this should be `{{ options.product_tools_tool_name }}`

Comment: Please post the dump as well

Comment: Okay I just added the `{{ dump(options.product_tools) }}` and the `{{ options.product_tools_tool_name }}` isnt working for me either?

Comment: As from your `dump` the 2nd part  (`tool`) is obsolete, e.g. `options.product_tools.tool_name` and `options.product_tools.tool_link`

Comment: Thanks, That is working all but my image now isn't `<img src="Image{{options.product_tools.tool_picture}}.src" alt="">`

Comment: Just follow your dump? `{{ options.product_tools.tool_picture.url }}`

Comment: Thanks for your help as always, slowly starting to get the hang of things!

Comment: @ShrockCo you have the wrong brackets when using `Image`, instead of `Image{{options.product_tools.tool_picture}}.src` use `Image({options.product_tools.tool_picture}).src`, `Image()` and not `Image{}`